# How to dynamically add states in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to dynamically add states within a controller.

app.stateProvider.state() is one way of doing this. But this doesn't work when I try to access any state using the URL. Navigating using URL only works for those states which are defined in config function.

Comment: It possible that you are looking for another solution. It [would be better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you would describe your problem first.

Comment: show your `angular.config` and explain your desired logic for routing